# Reducing callback-boilerplate in react redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get my head around using react and redux together. The Problem I have is, that it seems to me a lot of boilerplate code when the app gets complexer.

For example, take the Todo App from the redux [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/). Lets assume we want to extend the example, given a todo more properties:

- A title
- A due-date
- A owner
- more stuff

Now, I would add addtional Actions for modifying these properties:

```
const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
const REMOVE_TODO = 'REMOVE_TODO'
const TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO'
const CHANGE_TITLE = 'CHANGE_TITLE'
const CHANGE_DUEDATE = 'CHANGE_DUEDATE'
const CHANGE_OWNER = 'CHANGE_OWNER'
... more stuff ...
```

Now the callbacks for Todo must be extended by:

- onChangeTitle(title)
- onChangeDueDate(dueData)
- onChangeOwner(owner)
- ...

And the callbacks for TodoList must also be extended:

- onChangeTitle(index, title)
- ...

Finally the top level component must subscribe to all these callbacks and dispatch the action.

That seems to be a lot of boilerplate, especially when the component hierarchy goes even deeper.

My initial Idea would be, that Todo has only one callback:

- onChange(newData)

and TodoList:

- onChangeTodo(index, newData)

But than `newData` must be created in Todo, which basicly means implementing something like the [reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) there.

Am I getting the right Idea here? Can I reduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

`const TODO_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 'TODO_PROPERTY_UPDATE'`

Which would be used for all properties of a TODO (`title`, `duedate`, `owner`, etc.)

Action:

```
export function updateTodoProperty(index, property, propertyValue) {
  return { type: TODO_PROPERTY_UPDATE, index, property, propertyValue }
}
```

In your reducer:

```
case TODO_PROPERTY_UPDATE:
  return state.map((todo, index) => {
    if (index === action.index) {
      return Object.assign({}, todo, {
        [action.property]: action.propertyValue
      })
    }
    return todo
  })
```

Comment: That is Simple enough

Comment: I was Kind of afraid of doing something like this, because it make the presentational components Action aware. But maybe i was overthinking this.